# If inner product of a vector and a transformation is zero, prove T(v) = 0

Tags: inner-products

For $T: V \rightarrow V$ being a linear mapping, are these valid steps and a valid conclusion?

Given that $\langle \textbf{u} | T(\textbf{v}) \rangle$ = 0 for all $u,v \in V$.
$$ \text{if what we're given is true then} \\ \langle T(\textbf{v}) | \textbf{u} \rangle = 0 = \langle \textbf{u} | T(\textbf{v})\rangle \\ \text{By linearity,} \langle T(\textbf{v})- \textbf{u} | T(\textbf{v}) - \textbf{u} \rangle = 0 \\ \text{hence,} T(\textbf{v}) = \textbf{u}$$.

Are these steps valid given our original statement?

How would we show, given our original statement, that this is only true IF $T(v) = 0$?  \
\

Edit: Can someone check if this is correct as well? I can't see why it's wrong...
$$ \langle u | T(v) \rangle = 0 \\ \text{add to both sides} \quad \langle u | T(v) \rangle + \langle T(v) | T(v) \rangle = \langle T(v) | T(v) \rangle \\ \langle u + T(v) | T(v) \rangle = \langle T(v) | T(v) \rangle \\ \therefore u + T(v) = T(v) \qquad \text{by the uniqueness property} \\ u = 0 \qquad (???)$$

Comment: I'm not convinced about your linearity statement, the linearity works this way: $\langle u+\lambda . v | w \rangle = \langle u | w \rangle + \lambda . \langle v | w \rangle$. So in your case you just have : $\langle T(v) - T(v) | u \rangle = 0$ or $\langle T(v) | u - u \rangle = 0$...

Comment: About your edit, there is a problem: you cannot say that $\langle x|y \rangle= \langle z|y \rangle \Leftrightarrow x = z$, an example: $\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} | \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \rangle = 0 = \langle \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} | \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \rangle$ but $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}≠\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @RandomTourist How come?  
I have a theorem that says that if V is an inner product space and for all v,w in V if we have $\langle u | v \rangle = \langle u | w \rangle $ for all u in V, then $v = w$ and was proven by the positive definiteness of the inner product.  Ah I suspect it's because it isn't true for all u in V?

Comment: You guessed right. Like you said the theorem holds only if it works for all $u \in V$, so in our case we cannot use that because for all $v$, $T(v) \in T(V)$ and we don't know if $T(V) = V$ (and we precisely prove that $T(V) = \{ 0 \} \subsetneq V$)

Comment: And I think your theorem don't say _for all_ $v,w \in V$, I think it states that : if you pick $v,w \in V$ such as $\forall u \in V, \langle u | v \rangle = \langle u | w \rangle$ then $v = w$. If it does work for _every_ $v,w \in V$, then for any $u \in V$ by chosing $v = u$ and $w = 0$ you have $\langle u | u \rangle = \langle u | 0 \rangle$ then ${||u||}^2 = 0$ and so $\forall u \in V, u = 0$...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misusing the (bi)linearity of the inner product, as I said in my comment.

Here is my solution:

Let $v \in V$.
We have: $T(v) \in V$ ($T$ is an endomorphism), so: $\langle T(v) | T(v) \rangle = 0$ (property of $T$) then: $T(v) = 0$ (the inner product is definite).

We've just proved that:If $T$ has the given property then $\forall v \in V, T(v) = 0$.
The converse is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for this.  
How would this imply this is for all u,v in V? (as in my original question). Reading this, it just seems to me that this only proved that if $u$ (in my original question) and $T(v)$ happen to be equal, then we prove the result. But it doesnt seem like it proves for all $u$ in $V$.

Comment: Yes, since $\forall u,v \in V, \langle u|T(v) \rangle = 0$, I can indeed set $u = T(v)$ which results in $T(v) = 0$, but because I didn't specify anything about $v$ apart that $v \in V$, it does work for any $v$ in $V$, and so for any $v$ in $V$ we have that $T(v) = 0$. Is that enough clear?

Comment: yes it does! Thanks a lot!  
Wondering if you could check the edit I made in my original post, much appreciated!